# Отключается жёсткий диск во время простоя

Tags: windows-10

На моём ноутбуке отключается жёсткий диск во время простоя. Зайдя в панель управления -> электропитание, в разделе отключение жёсткого диска я указал 0, сохранил и перезагрузил компьютер, но ничего не изменилось. Жёсткий диск как отключался, так и отключается. Быть может, необходимо что-то править в реестре? Или использовать какую-то утилиту. (OS Windows 10 Pro, система стоит на SSD)

Comment: Похожая проблема была когда жесткий диск работал в боксе и подключался через usb, проблема решилась сама собой

Comment: В настройках питания разве ничего нет на эту тему?

Comment: 0 в питании 100% должно действовать, причем без перезагрузки. А что за диск, может что-то встроенное в диск? И ещё, если это USB, то у USB отдельное управление питанием, тоже надо 0 ставить

Comment: Не забудьте про различные профили питания от сети и батареи.

Comment: Проверил ещё раз настройки электропитания, 0 стоит ВЕЗДЕ (от батареи и от сети). HDD стоковый от Asus K501U. Может быть, эта настройка работает для системного диска, а не для остальных томов?

Comment: @Programmer Нет. Для всех. Но просветите нас: это дополнительный диск? Каким интерфейсом подключен?

Comment: Да, это дополнительный диск (система стоит на ssd), подключён интерфейсом Serial ATA